# Git configuration user.name doesn't work

Tags: git, git-config

I installed Git for Windows 7 today. I don't know much about Git yet and I'm following http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup and videos from YouTube on that subject. On the videos people install Git and go to the command line and use

```
git config --global user.name = "My Name"
```

and

```
git config --global user.email = "email@example.com"
```

and it creates `.gitconfig` file in `C:/Users/admin/.gitconfig` with correct values for them.

After running the above lines of code three times this is what I got in that file:

```
[user]
    name = =
    email = =
    name = =
```

Why isn't it working? I followed the official tutorial and I see that it works for other people on YouTube but not for me.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You're not using the correct syntax: there shouldn't be any equal sign between `user.name` and `"My name"`, or between `user.email` and `"email@example.com"`. For instance, when you run

```
git config --global user.name = "My Name"
```

the command interprets the `=` character as the string value passed to the `user.name` key, and the rest of the line (`"My Name"`) is silently ignored. That's why your `.gitconfig` file ends up containing

```
[user]
    name = =
    email = =
```

Everything should work if you use the correct syntax:

[image]

See also [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42879577/2541573) about relevant changes in Git 2.13.

Comment: You're right, that's my mistake. After seeing another answer I noticed that I had redundant `=` there.

Answer (score 10):

There is no "=" for the parameters user.name and user.email, just use spaces. From the same page -

The first thing you should do when you install Git is to set your user name and e-mail address. This is important because every Git commit uses this information, and it’s immutably baked into the commits you pass around:

- $ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
- $ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com

Answer (score 3):

Note: that kind of syntax error (`git config --global user.email = "email@example.com"`) will be better reported by Git 2.13+ (Q2 2017)

See [commit 9442555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94425552f308946456bb7823d0a1dd72ebd30bdd), [commit 13b9a24](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13b9a24e58f736b70e48846cf7e5b7cfa66c3fec), [commit 862e80a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/862e80a413e45d34834ecd573e5c6b39e38ba850), [commit afb6c30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/afb6c30b27069db666a0004f4b6b05c067170088) (23 Feb 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 066c38c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/066c38ca17efcacc363f5a8973cc3a118defda5a), 10 Mar 2017)</sup>

> `user.email` that consists of only [cruft chars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruft#Software) should consistently
>   error out, but didn't.

That means this will now fail:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=" .;<>" git commit --allow-empty -m foo
fatal: name consists only of disallowed characters: .;<>

GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="" GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="" git commit --allow-empty -m foo 
fatal: no email was given and auto-detection is disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

For those coming to this much later, and want to simply have their credentials stored because SSH isn't available, use the following:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no space in my command:

```
git config --global user.name="parsecer"
```

should be

```
git config --global user.name = "parsecer"
```

Answer (score -3):

use

sudo git config --global user.name "My Name"