# Git config issue w/VSCode and Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, visual-studio-code

***After some trial and error I was able to change the permissions of the `.gitconfig` file in my local users `/home/` directory. This permission change allowed me to add both `user.name` and `user.email`. I apologize if this wasted anyone's time and I do appreciate all of the help. Specifically @phd, @jD3V and @VonC***

I am really banging my head against my desk with this one.

I have a remote GitHub repo that I have cloned locally to my machine and I am making edits to the playbook. When I go to commit the changes to GitHub VSCode throws an error:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: no email was given and auto-detection is disabled
[2022-04-23T18:08:35.512Z] > git config --get-all user.name [1ms]
```

I have run into this issue before, no big deal. This is a fresh install of Pop!_OS so I had not yet edited my git config. I enter the following -

```
git config --global user.name My_GitHub_Username
```

Followed by -

```
git config --global user.email My_email_name@gmail.com
```

When entered they both seem to run correctly as I do not get any errors thrown when entered. However when I check the `git config` with `git config --list` nothing returns in the terminal. When I run it again running as root, I see my username -

```
username@pop-os:~$ sudo git config --list
user.name=My_GitHub_username
user.email=My_email_name@gmail.com
```

Trying to commit the code again throws the same error. I have checked similar threads/solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962152/git-config-global-user-email-wont-let-me-change-email-after-reinstalling), [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/git+config+file+generator) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593043/git-configuration-user-name-doesnt-work), all of which have not solved my issue.

*I forgot to include initially that I have tried running both as `sudo` and have the same results. Here is the output of `sudo nano ~/.gitconfig -*

```
[alias]
    lg1 = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
    lg2 = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)' --all
    lg = !"git lg1"
[color]
    ui = true
[help]
    autocorrect = 3
```

Would I just go ahead and add the `[user]` alias with the `user.name` and `user.email` options filled in?

Any ideas what I might be doing incorrectly? I am not super familiar with git but would love any and all advice.

Comment: `sudo` damn it!

Comment: Well first of all, you tagged the question wrong. Secondly, you have different layers of git configurations, which is why, when you use the `--list` flag as the `ROOT` user, your getting a different result, but the result your getting as `ROOT` user is irrelivent, you need to edit your `.gitconfig` configuration files directly using `nano ~/.gitconfig` (or if your using vscode, you can use `code ~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: As @VonC and phd have already suggested.

Comment: I forgot to include that I did infact also try running the commands as sudo with the same result @Phd

Comment: @FRALEWHALE Yes, that exactly the problem. Do not use `sudo` when you do not need it (and you almost never need it) and especially when you do not understand it.

Comment: @phd I have also tried it without `sudo` and that did not work either, so then what would my solution be? When I run it I get  without `sudo` I get an error - `warning: unable to access '/home/USERNAME/.gitconfig': Permission denied` Which is obviously a permissions issues but I am not sure how my local user does not have access to that file. Also I like to think I understand `sudo` well enough. It did strike me as odd as I have never had to run it before while making git config edits. Could you also tell me how I tagged the question wrong? Would this be more applicable in the SuperUser board?

Comment: @FRALEWHALE "*`warning: unable to access '/home/USERNAME/.gitconfig': Permission denied` Which is obviously a permissions issues but I am not sure how my local user does not have access to that file*" Very easy — you had used `sudo` before and thus changed the ownership of the file. The fix is `sudo chown USERNAME .gitconfig` or even  `sudo chown -R USERNAME $HOME`, not `sudo git`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exand on the comment, `git config --global` do modify `~/.gitconfig`, which is `/home/<you>/.gitconfig`.

That differs from `sudo xxx`, which executes command as root.
`root` home folder is `/root`.
And `/root/.gitconfig` was not modified by your initial `git config` commands.

In general, *not* using `root`, is possible, is a sensible route to follow.